# How to get element id using alias attribute in Mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

How to get element id using alias attribute in Mootools

```
<input type="text" alias="school_name" value="" id="test_school" name="test_school">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the $$ function to return an element based on a css selector. You can use the css attribute selector syntax to retrieve elements based on an attribute.

```
// Returns all inputs with an alias of school_name
var els = $$('input[alias=school_name]');
```

This will return an array of elements.

You can then do els[0].id to retrieve the id of the first element (or loop through the elements as you see fit)

Comment: I think you need to express that with 'input[alias="school_name"]'

Comment: Double-dollar is going to be deprecated in the next major version of MooTools, please use `document.getElements()` instead.